# How to create views depending on user roles and how to create login - Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile

Are there any examples out there on how to create a user login with flutter and node js? I'd also like to know if anyone has implemented role based fluter apps with views for admin only etc

Answer (score 0):

Never done Flutter with NodeJs but right off the bat I can say that if im  displaying some information based on userRole, once I get a hold of the role just use a if statement to display the appropriate view.